# Actual size of an object from its image

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, camera-calibration

I would like to calculate the actual size of an object from its image taken at a fixed distance from the Camera. The focal length of the camera is known. Now how will I able to calculate the actual size of the object only with the image data??

I am implementing the program using Opencv.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am little confused with this pixels and centimeter conversions.

Comment: Draw a picture. You'll probably need some basic trigonometry.

Comment: May be...Camera Calibration plays a vital role I guess..:)

Answer (score 2):

The size of the object to the distance from the camera is in the same ratio as the size of the image to the focal length.

So...

```
 s = is/fl * d
```

where `s` is the size of the object, `is` is the size of the object in the image, `fl` is the focal length, and `d` is distance to the camera.

Comment: Thank you..:) And btw when i find the size of the object in image it is in terms of pixels. How will I able to convert it into say centimeter? So far what I have did is to find the dpi and print size from GIMP and obtain a factor to convert pixels to cm. I am concerned if its right or not?

Comment: Wherever you got the focal length from should give you some idea of the size of the image sensor inside the camera. The size of each physical pixel in the sensor should be the size of the sensor divided by the pixel size of a full sized image (you'll have to decide if 'size' refers to width or height, or get more complex for area). I don't think the DPI in Gimp will be the right number - that's usually more related to printing and scaled to image sizes that are printed.

Answer (score 1):

This question on the photography exchange may prove useful reading:

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12434/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-of-an-object-in-a-photo

The top answer provides a general purpose equation easily manipulated for your purposes, and gives an excellent, detailed coverage. Best of luck :).